# How do i convert foreachloop into a parallel foreachloop while using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, parallel-foreach

The Problem is I'm using linqs also ?

```
foreach (var item in ints.Select((x, i) => new { OldIndex = i, Value = x, NewIndex = -1 })
                .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
                .Select((x, i) => new { OldIndex = x.OldIndex, Value = x.Value, NewIndex = i })
                .OrderBy(x => x.OldIndex))
                Console.Write(item + "\n");
```

Comment: Have you searched the internet for how a parallel for loop works? You will definitely find resources about that there!! Please do some research and just ask if you have a specific error or problem!! Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: arallel.ForEach(delegates, handler => 
                            {
                                 //Do your thing with the handler and may the thread-safety be with you.
                            });